# Shouldn't the input state of Deutsh-Jozsa's algorithm look like $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}\otimes |1\rangle$ rather than $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}|1\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, textbook-and-exercises, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm, terminology-and-notation

According to this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsch%E2%80%93Jozsa_algorithm) the initial state in Deutsch–Jozsa algorithm is written as follows:
$$|0\rangle^{\otimes n} |1\rangle$$

shouldn't it look like this?:

$$|0\rangle^{\otimes n} \otimes |1\rangle$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a convention. People tend to write $|01 \rangle$ instead of $|0 \rangle \otimes |1\rangle $, but they mean the same thing. In this case,
$$ \overbrace{|0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle \otimes \cdots \otimes |0\rangle}^{n \ \ times} \otimes|1\rangle = |0\rangle^{\otimes n} \otimes |1\rangle = |0\rangle^{\otimes n} |1\rangle$$

So it is just a matter of notation.